# HTML form using POST to get PHP passing data to MS Access

Tags: php, html, ms-access

Hi I have two pieces of code set up

```
<form action="Index2.php" method="POST">
    <p>Name:</p>
    <input type="text" name="name">

    <p>Last Name:</p>
    <input type="text" name="lname">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and this PHP file named Index2.php

```
<?php

$connection = odbc_connect("Dashboard","","") or die ("Unable to Connect to the DB");

$name=$_POST['name'];
$last_name=$_POST['lname'];

$sql = "
    INSERT INTO tableone (Name, Last_Name)
    VALUES ('$name', '$last_name')
";

odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
?>
```

That I have tried in a separate file to make sure connects and pass the info to the database but when I run the form it does not pass the data to MS Access and shows me the PHP code on a blank page, am I missing some sort of escaping from PHP?

Comment: can you try this instead:
` $sql = "
    INSERT INTO tableone (Name, Last_Name)
    VALUES ('" . $name . "', '" . $last_name . "')
";`

Comment: Does any Php code get interpreted in your server environment?  Something like `<?php echo 'hello earth';` in its own file.

Comment: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page) which talks about configuration issues. Sounds like your php code is not being processed.

Comment: I thought this most likely will be the problem, I will check it and try to solve the excecution of the php code on my environment

Comment: <?php echo 'hello earth';?> this is displayed, so php gets excecuted

Comment: @IamCavic, I tried this sentece, althought it does not give me any error it does not get written into the Access DB. They query is right, I tried alone, I think the problem is with php and html, something do not clicked right there

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this and its working.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit]))
{
$name=$_POST['name'];
$last_name=$_POST['lname'];
$con=odbc_connect("abc","","");
$sql="INSERT INTO tableone(name,lastname) VALUES('$name','$last_name')";
if(odbc_exe($con,$sql))
{
    echo "<br>Data Added<br>Please wait ,Page is redirecting";  
    header("refresh:1;url=index.php");
}
else
{
    echo "Error";
}
}   
?>
```

Comment: besides a typo on the second line this is not solving OP question. The question is why his code is not parsed but the raw php appears

Comment: I tried this without the typo on line 2 (that´s ok) and apparently the php code is excecuted but the odbc sentece to MS Access never pass thru as it did not placed the data there

Comment: NOTE: No message was displayed at all, not even raw php code this time, just blank page.

Comment: Finally worked like this: <?php 

$name=$_POST['name'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
    
$connection = odbc_connect("Dashboard","","") or die ("Unable to Connect to the DB");

$sql = "
  INSERT INTO tableone (Name, Last_Name)
  VALUES ('$name', '$lname')
 ";
 
 odbc_exec($connection, $sql);

?> Thank you all for the help!